# Json recognised as String

Tags: javascript, json, django

I am trying to read the response of the server that gives me the following JSON:

```
{"result": "Success", "message": "[{\"model\": \"mysite.userprofile\", \"pk\": 1}, {\"model\": \"mysite.userprofile\", \"pk\": 4}]"}
```

When I try to read it I get as is a String. If I try to parse it is not possible as it gives me

> Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

which  means that is a Json already.

So this code:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '/search/?city=&radius=',
            success: function (data) {
                //data = JSON.parse(data);
                var ul = document.getElementById("contact-list");
                console.log("JSON?  "+data.message[0]); // Print [ which is the first char

                for (var x = 0; x < data.message.length; x++){
                     // iterate throw every character in the message
                }
```

So inside the properties ('result' and 'message') it appears as there is a String instead of a Json

And here is the server side:

```
def search_profiles_by_loc(request):
    if request.method == "POST" and request.is_ajax():
        city = request.POST.get('city', False)
        all_profiles = UserProfile.objects.all()
        response_data = {}
        response_data['result'] = 'Success'
        response_data['message'] = serializers.serialize('json', all_profiles)
        return HttpResponse(JsonResponse(response_data), content_type="application/json")
```

I tried a lot of things nothing work

Comment: inside message there is a json string you have to parse that then only you will be able to use it

Comment: When you use dataType: 'json' there is no need to use JSON.parse()

Comment: Either use `JSON.parse()` on the string. Or send it as an array, without enclosing with `"`

Comment: A JSON *(-string)* is always a string! There is no such thing as a JSON-object. There are only objects. I'd guess that this misconception probably lead you to *manually* JSON-encode the `message` in the backend before you add it to the response. You should fix that mistake on the server rather than trying to work around this in the client.

Comment: I see @Thomas I added the server side. If I do not ecode the message I do not get it well

Comment: what happens when you write `response_data['message'] = all_profiles` ?

Answer (score 2):

As harish-reddy said, the dataType property sets the behaviour to what you expect the response to be. That said the "data" argument of the success function is already a JavaScript object.

Refer to http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

As arpit-solanki mentioned the message property inside the response object is not an array, but is interpreted as a string (notice the starting '"'), therefor you either change the server side to send you an actual array or you must JSON.parse(data.message) to obtain its content.

Comment: I did it before, but I misunderstood as it said undefined, but yes I can access the  object inside. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The response you are receiving is already executed by JSON.stringify.Either you must use JSON.parse or change the logic at the server end